# how to provide multiple hostnames in the datafiles for postman

Tags: postman, newman

Command used:

```
newman run Collection.json --delay-request 2000 --timeout-request 240000 -e env.json -d data.json -r cli,html -k -n 1 --color on
data file:
[
{"Url": "12:9002"},
{"Url": "13:9002"}
]
```

I Have this url defined in the collection.json but the problem is, it only runs for the first host not the second one.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Can you explain a bit more as to what your scenario is and what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: we have 4 environments and each environment we have 10 servers, now we need to run automated postman tests for each environment from jenkins after we deploy the app to the each environment. so developers provided only one collection.json and one env.json to run the automated tests. so my doubt is how to run the tests using newman for each environment for multiple hosts., how to maintain the env.json file or data.json file?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you've specified the `-n 1` option in your `newman run ...` command, which limits the number of iterations to 1. Removing it from the command should restore expected behaviour.